# Population Dynamics and Differential Equations

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

I was studying Non-Equilibrium phase transition models and got stuck on the very first simple model that I was looking at. The Population of species is given by $n(t)$ the transition rates are

$P(n:t;n+1, t+\Delta t) = \lambda n$
$P(n:t,n-1, t+\Delta t) = n$.

The resulting master equation and dynamics is as follows, We use the notation $P_n(t)$ for the probability of population $n$ at time $t$.

$\frac{dP_n(t)}{dt} = \lambda (n-1) P_{n-1}(t-\Delta t) + (n+1) P_{n+1}(t-\Delta t) - (1 + \lambda) P_n(t - \Delta t)$

The moment generating function $g(x,t) = \sum_n x^n P_n(t)$. We obtain the differential equation below,

$\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} = (1 - x)(1-\lambda x) \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$

I get all this, the solution of the above using separation of variables I get is very different from the one presented in the book.

$g(x,t) = \frac{(1-\lambda x)e^{(1-\lambda t)} - (1-x)}{(1-\lambda x)e^{(1-\lambda t)} - \lambda(1-x)}$

Clearly, the above solution is not obtained by separation of variables.

Help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a transport equation with variable coefficients and zero forcing. You should use the method of characteristics

Comment: @CalvinKhor, Thank you. I think I got it.